# Deduct from total pool of hours and minutes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to have a cell which has a given number of hours and minutes allocated and then add events which deduct from that time and show the total hours and minutes left. For example if I had 240 hours & 40 minutes and took 40 minute appointment and another 36 minute appointment I should be left with 239 hours and 24 minutes. But I am doing something wrong with my excel formula, is there another better way of doing this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
=E3-SUM(E4:E11)
```

You also need to list your times as hh:mm:ss
E4 should be 00:40:00, E5 should be 00:36:00. They way you have them, it looks
like 40 seconds and 36 seconds (depending on formatting)
Also note that working with days you must multiply by 24 and hours multiply by 60